# Real Scheduled jobs are returned in the query when running test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a SOQL query like below running in a test method.

```
@isTest(seeAllData=FALSE)
static void scheduledJob_Test(){
    List<CronTrigger> cronTriggersList = [select CronJobDetail.Name, 
                                                CronJobDetailId, Id 
                                                from CronTrigger 
                                                where CronJobDetail.Name 
                                                like 'Scheduled Job%'];
}
```

Surprisingly it is returning the number of jobs scheduled in production. Is this expected? I was expecting the above query to return zero rows as nothing is scheduled in test context and `seeAllData` flag is set to FALSE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> By default, when executing Unit Tests in Salesforce, the data in the list below is visible.  Largely speaking, these items are considered your Salesforce org’s Metadata.

- Custom Setting definitions – includes Field Names and Types
- SObject definitions for both Standard and Custom Objects – includes
  Field  Names and Types, Lookup Relationships, Master-Detail
  Relationships, Picklist Values
- AsyncApexJob
- CronTrigger
- ApexClass
- ApexTrigger
- ApexComponent
- ApexPage
- Organization
- Picklist values (ie Opportunity Stage Names)*
- Record Types*
- Email Templates*
- User Profile.* To get standard user Profile in a unit test, use:
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];

  The above behaviour is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm) and hence its as per the design and you will see PROD CronTrigger .